# What's the reason that "rm -rf a/b" says "a/b is not empty"?

Tags: rm

The following script *sometimes* gives me things like `can't remove a/b as it's not empty`

```
ssh -T user@host <<EOF
  cd somewhere
  rm -rf a/b    
EOF
```

But I log in to the server and execute `rm -rf a/b` then I never had the problem.

There are other processes that are generating files to `a/b`, is that related?

Anyway, how to make a script that will ensure "a/b" will be deleted?

Comment: That's funny, `rm -rf` should always succeed, short of permission issues. Ask the script to print debugging output if the removal fails.`ls -laR a/b` should suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rmdir(2)` will fail if the directory is not empty. If another process is creating files while `rm(1)` is removing them, it will not know to delete them and consequently when it comes time for `rm(1)` to try to delete what it believes should be an empty directory, it will fail with the error you've posted.

One way to delete the directory in the face of concurrent file creations in the directory is to rename it:

```
mv a a~
rm -rf a~
```

It's possible that this may not work if the processes creating the files in `a/b` are not doing so by path (`open(2)` vs. `openat(2)`).

I am assuming that the process(es) that creates files in `a/b` will recreate that directory if it does not exist, or will handle failure gracefully if it does not exist. Since you are already trying to delete the directory from under other processes, that seems like a safe assumption.

Comment: thanks, glusterfs is healing directory and cannot heal it normally by some bug in glusterfs, so mv a directory to diferent name and rm is fixing it.

Answer (score 16):

> There are other processes that are generating files to a/b, is that related?

Very possibly.  It might be that `rm -rf` first removes all files, then removes all directories.  Under the hood, the `rmdir` system call for removing a directory
will fail if the directory is not empty.  You might have a race condition going on, where `rm -rf` checks that the directory is empty, and it is; another process then creates a new file; finally `rm -rf` calls `rmdir`, but another process creates a file beforehand.

Faheem's advice is good: put an `ls` into your error condition

```
ssh -T user@host <<EOF
  cd somewhere
  rm -rf a/b || ( ls -a a/b && exit 1 )
EOF
```

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: The `&&` should be `;` or else `ls` failure will prevent the script from exiting.

Comment: Yep. `ls` shows that there are new files in that dir. I'm going to give the `mv` solution a try.

Comment: @R, that is not true. If `ls` fails, the subshell will return `ls`'s failure code. the '`&& exit 1`' is necessary to ensure that if `ls` *succeeds*, the sub-shell still returns an error code. If you substitute it for '||', you will mask the true error code for `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of very high race condition: next command removes outdated files and then removes empty directories:

```
find /somedir -type f -atime +3 -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty rm -f; find /somedir -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -not -name "*.empty" -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty -I{} mv {} {}.empty; sleep 30; find /somedir -type d -name '*.empty' -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty rm -rf
```

Or step by step:

```
find /somedir -type f -atime +3 -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty rm -f;
find /somedir -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -not -name "*.empty" -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty -I{} mv {} {}.empty;
sleep 30;
find /somedir -type d -name '*.empty' -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty rm -rf;
```

**sleep 30** is necessary to all processes to finish writing into the removing direcory.

**WARNING: you can lose your new data** (in my case it is cache so I don't care).